# Quodlibet couldn't connect to a device backend

Tags: 13.04, devices, mtp, quodlibet

I'm new to Quod Libet but I want to like it. Every other music app has disappointed me in some way and so far QL disappoints me least. It's not perfect but I'm trying very hard to make it work. However, I can't get my devices to be recognized properly.

I have an ancient iPod Mini and an HTC One X. I was previously using Ubuntu 12.04 and Quod Libet 2.3.2 and I could get the iPod to work fine but the HTC was giving me trouble, mostly because of MTP issues, I presume. In the hope that upgrading my OS would help, I'm now at Ubuntu 13.04. However, the Media Devices browser won't even load now. This is what I see when I open quodlibet from command line:

> W: Initializing device backend.
>  W: Couldn't connect to a device
>   backend.
>  W: No device backend, Media Devices browser disabled.

The default Ubuntu 13.04 version is still 2.4, so I tried the quodlibet stable repo (`ppa:lazka/ppa`) and got 2.5.1, which gave me the same error. I'm now using the unstable repo (`ppa:lazka/dumpingplace`) with version 3.0.1 but still getting the same error.

What might I be doing wrong? I've looked around online and I can't find hardly anything relevant. One person recommended making sure udisks2 was present, but I appear to have that installed. That's about all I've found.

These are my other current related versions, in case it helps:
Audio device: GStreamer (autoaudiosink)
Mutagen: 1.21.-1
GTK+: 3.6.4
PyGObject: 3.8.0
GStreamer: 1.0.6.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for also filing a bug report [1] :)

The workaround until this is fixed is calling

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.UDisks /org/freedesktop/UDisks org.freedesktop.UDisks.EnumerateDevices
```

before starting QL.

[1] https://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/issues/detail?id=1213

Comment: Thanks, @lazka! Sorry for the double post, but I was concerned it was Ubuntu-specific and that's why I brought it here. I'm still trying to figure out how to get my HTC One X to be recognized properly as a device, but that may be more of a separate MTP issue.